# É possível modificar o que o usuário vai inserir em um formulário?

Tags: php, html

É possível fazer com que aquilo que o usuário insira no formulário esteja já previamente modificado?

Exemplo: Ele inserir "Oi" no `<textarea>` e nos meus resultados eu tiver um "5 Oi", sendo o '5 ' inserido por mim mesmo através de código.,

Trecho do que tentei pelas respostas:

```
let comment = document.getElementById('comment')
let valorAdicional = '5'
let valorDigitado = ''
comment.onkeyup = function(){
  comment.value = valorAdicional + comment.value
}

textarea id="comment" maxlength="500"
input type="submit" name="post_comment" value="Enviar"
```

Não funcionou, apenas preencheu com os dados colocados mesmo, sem acrescentar

Comment: Se você quiser isso em tempo real, tipo, o usuário digita e ja substitui na hora, só com PHP não tem como, mas se quiser fazer depois de enviar o formulário, ai sim tem como, quer atualizar a pergunta ou manter assim mesmo ? se for isso mesmo, a resposta do Andrei ja resolve.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR tem rasão.. Se for em tempo real é necessário usar javascript

Comment: Quero que antes de chegar a resposta ela já esteja com algo pré adicionado antes, posso sim usar javascript caso tenham uma solução de como fazer

Answer (score 0):

Só você retornar para a variavel que deseja, o value da textbox que o usuario digitou somando com outra string. Um metodo chamado concatenação.

Tente isso

```
    $idade = "5";
    $valorAdd = "hue";

       $idadeAtual = $valorAdd." - ".$idade;

       echo $idadeAtual;
```

Terá a seguinte saida nesse caso

```
hue - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso em tempo real com `JS` e já receber modificado no `PHP`

Um exemplo simples, a cada caractere digitado, ele coloca um `5` na frente, ai você pode fazer da forma que preferir.

```js
let campo = document.getElementById('campo')
let valorAdicional = 5
let valorDigitado = ''
campo.onkeyup = function(){
  campo.value = valorAdicional + campo.value
}
```

```html
<textarea id="campo"></textarea>
```

Dessa maneira basta você receber no `PHP` assim:

```
$campo = $_POST['campo'];
```

Já se for só com `PHP` basta concatenar

```
$campo = "5" . $_POST['campo']; // Valor que foi digitado no campo
```

Comment: Acho que essa resposta foi a mais próxima de entender mesmo mas comigo não funcionou :/ Segue trecho do código, ta retornando apenas o que eu insiro, veja nas respostas vou postar

Comment: @GiovanyHenrique Você colocou a parte de `JS` no final do arquivo dentro de `<script></script>` ?

Comment: Coloquei antes do formulário o script js que você passou sim, dentro de <script></script>, segue na pergunta como está o codigo

Comment: @GiovanyHenrique Da alguem erro no `console`? pois no exemplo que postei está funcionando, caso estejá dando algum erro no `console`, poderia me passar?

Comment: Nenhum erro mas também não adc os caracteres, não teria um modo de colocar algo fixo antes da resposta como explicado no topico?

Comment: Caso você queira algo já no `textarea` antes mesmo do usuario começar a digitar, você pode ter `<textarea value="5"></textarea>`, mas deveria estar funcionando o codigo que passei, você poderia postar seu codigo completo no `JSFiddle` ?

Comment: Sim já está funcional mas não satisfez o que pretendia, queria deixar fixo algo junto com o que o usuário digitaria mas acho que não existe possibilidade

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi vc quer alterar o registro enquanto o usuario digita no campo (creio eu que esse texto pré escrito vai vir de um select no banco)
Caso vc esteja usando algum framework php, você pode usar o método ajax, assim vc faz uma requisição sem atualizar a pagina
Ou então caso seja php puro, apenas faça um select no banco e concatene o valor usando a função .keyup do jquery. Exemplo:

```
var txtCampo = document.getElementById('id_do_input');
txtCampo.onkeyup = function(){
  //chame aqui um script php ou faça uma requisição ajax
  campo.value = "o valor que vc quer" + txtCampo.value
};
```